# Libgdx Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, libgdx

I haven't worked with libgdx for the last 3 months and now I tried to make a simple game but when i imported the libgdx jars and runned the app on my mobile phone(Android), it crashed. 
I found on the net that ADT version handles all the libs. So I've putted the Libgdx jars in the libs folder, but I still the app crashes.

LogCat:

> Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity
>   {com.class.path/com.class.path.ExampleActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

after this i have 10 references at android classes (ex: at android.app.ActivityThread.main...), and than i have this:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.onResume(AndroidApplication.java:223)

On line 223 in the libgdx source I've found this:

> ((AndroidInput)getInput()).registerSensorListeners();

ExampleActivity:

> public class ExampleActivity extends AndroidApplication {
>
> ```
> @Override
> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     initialize(new Game(), false);
> }
> ```
>
> }

Game:
public class Game implements ApplicationListener {

```
@Override
public void create() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void pause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void render() {
}

@Override
public void resize(int arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void resume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

PS: Sorry for my bad English

Comment: add your logcat and relavant code

Comment: Are you seeing multiple exceptions?  Its odd for libGDX to fail in onResume if onCreate completed successfully.  I've sometimes seen errors in onResume if onCreate fails in an ugly way, so check if other exceptions are also being dumped out?

Comment: Odd, not sure how AndroidInput would be null at that point.

Comment: Use the setup ui file found in the libgdx archive, it will set up the project properly.

Comment: I just used an older version of libgdx v0.9 and now everything is ok

Answer (score 0):

I happened to encounter this question too. and fixed it by use the code based on [ModelPreiviewApp](https://github.com/ASneakyFox/libgdx-fbxconv-gui/blob/3bc6c0a3efc47c757e24090f9a173c4ed13d830a/core/src/asf/modelpreview/ModelPreviewApp.java)

```
private boolean backFaceCulling = true;
private boolean alphaBlending = false;
private float alphaTest = -1;


public void setAlphaBlending(ModelInstance modelInstance, boolean alphaBlendingEnabled){
    if(modelInstance != null){
        if(alphaBlendingEnabled){
            for (Material mat : modelInstance.materials) {
                mat.set(new BlendingAttribute(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA));
            }
        }else{
            for (Material mat : modelInstance.materials) {
                mat.remove(BlendingAttribute.Type);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void setAlphaTest(ModelInstance modelInstance, float alphaTestValue){
    if(modelInstance != null){
        if(alphaTestValue>=0){
            for (Material mat : modelInstance.materials) {
                mat.set(new FloatAttribute(FloatAttribute.AlphaTest, alphaTestValue));
            }
        }else{
            for (Material mat : modelInstance.materials) {
                mat.remove(FloatAttribute.AlphaTest);
            }
        }
    }
}


public void setBackFaceCulling(ModelInstance modelInstance, boolean backFaceCullinEnabled) {

    if (modelInstance != null) {
        if (backFaceCullinEnabled) {
            for (Material mat : modelInstance.materials) {
                mat.remove(IntAttribute.CullFace);
            }
        } else {
            for (Material mat : modelInstance.materials) {
                mat.set(new IntAttribute(IntAttribute.CullFace, 0));
            }
        }
    }
}

public void onModelLoaded(ModelInstance modelInstance) {
    ...
    setBackFaceCulling(modelInstance, true);
    setAlphaBlending(modelInstance, false);
    setAlphaTest(modelInstance, -1);
}
```